# unique identifier violation when updating using JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to update a table but keep getting an error saying `ORA-00001: unique constraint`

It is failing on a list `.itemList(product.getproductItemList())`

I added this to set the products:

```
updatedProducts.getProductItemList().forEach(product -> product.setProduct(updatedProduct));
```

Comment: Where is that deletion you mention at the beginning?

Comment: umm you are using frontend to manage your data - that is something i would remove. You should rather expose methods to remove selected item(s). But that is out of the question scope

Comment: @Antoniossss you select what product is to be deleted on the front, then it is sent to the endpoint.

Comment: You just wrote something else. 1) its good it is done that way 2) review what you are writing.

Comment: Also why are you not setting new values on managed `campaing` object but you introduce some sort of "duplicate" object that is unmanaged? `Campaign updatedCampaign = campaign.toBuilder()` why do you need that? You want to create new entity or modify existing one ?

Comment: As for the last screenshot - this is not what I have told you to do. foreach was supposed to be AFTER you build object. Obviously what hou have done wont compile as foreach does not return a value.

Comment: When you call `saveAndFlush` does the next call go through `EntityManager.persist` or through `EntityManager.merge`? Try debugging to find out, if the stack trace doesn't show it. I suspect it's going through `persist`, when it should be going through `merge`.

Answer (score 1):

To this line

```
.campaignItemList(newCampaign.getCampaignItemList())
```

add

`getCampaingsItemList().foreach(item=>item.setCampaing(updatedCampaing));`

as `CampaingItem` is this is where relation is stored (owner of FK)

```
Campaign updatedCampaign = ...builder stuff...
                                   .build(); <-- HERE YOU SEE I HAVE ENDED BUILDED MANIPULATION


//This is separate line of code executed somewhere before saveAndFlush and after `build();`    
updatedCampaing.getCampaingsItemList().forEach(item=>item.setCampaing(updatedCampaing));
```

IMHO what is happening here, that JPA tries to create new campaing items but using "old" relation (campaing id + item id) causing constraint violation. Still it is a guess as you are mentioning some deletions that are not present in the code.

Comment: I don't get it... Assigning list throws unique constraint violation right away?

Comment: @Drew1208 thas my point - you are not doing what I wrote. Please notice that foreach is not an argument to any setter nor any other method call. Moreover if you take closer look it is done AFTER `build()`. You are doing it all wrong. It is a separate line of code.

Comment: What error????? You better check my comments in the code, maybe those will clear things for you

Comment: Well I cannot tell what you have done since you have only show incorrect usage on your screenshot. Pitty it is not working.

Comment: I have no clue why some DB constrains would break on given line since there is not DB operations at that point..

Comment: Okay so at least we have cleared that. Can you try to create `updatedCampaing` from scratch insteed of using builder (because you will copy ID as well using builder)?

Comment: Also you didnt stated what would be expected outcome: should it update existing entity or create new one